# How do i color a specific size that i mentioned?

Tags: html, css

How do i specify a particular size ,example width and height at a particular place and fill it with a specific color?without using any tags like < h1 > or < p >.I mean

```
         width="500" height="200"
```

and make that area colored? How do i do that ? I have been trying but unable to make it.I made it using < h1 > tags but does it work without using any < h1 > or some other tags? Its necessary for me to make a particular area in my window to be colored without syntax.so Please help me

Comment: Can you provide your html?  The question is a bit unclear.

Comment: If you question is about html, how can there be an alternative to using tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use  then play with the class you add to it :

```
<span class="myspan">your text</span>
```

then in css

```
<style>
.myspan{
color:blue;
background-color:grey;
width:200px;
height:50px:
font-size:15pt;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div wrapped around and apply a background color

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create new elements without tags.

The only exception is to add *generated content* with the `::before` or `::after` pseudo elements, but functionality is or may be limited, depending on your exact wishes and your current implementation.

These elements do not work in IE7 or below, so you should only go to this resort when your markup is fixed (i.e. not modifiable).

See [this fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mZJsf/2/).